# Cancel the exit event in vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have some text fields that require validation in a VBA Userform. what i'd like to happen is when a user exits a textbox, the format is checked, and if it fails, move the focus back to that text box (effectively stopping the exit event in its tracks)

```
Private Sub Form_RCAIncidentDay_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If Len(Form_RCAIncidentDay.Value) > 2 Or Not IsNumeric(Form_RCAIncidentDay.Value) Then
Form_RCAIncidentDay.Value = ""
MsgBox "Please enter a valid day ('00' Format)", vbOKOnly, "Validation Error"
Form_RCAIncidentDay.SetFocus
End If

End Sub
```

The Validation is fine, but the focus isn't shifting back, and the cursor is showing in the next field in the tab index.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before `End If`:

```
Cancel = True
```

You can also remove the `.SetFocus` line.

Just a thought, but perhaps it would be easier to use a combo box to select the day or even date?